# Answer to ''how many are you''

Tags: english-to-german

How do I answer "I'm alone" in German to the question: "How many are you?" For example at a restaurant.

> Ich bin allein hier/eins/ein?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the phrasing of the question, though "Ich bin alleine hier" should work in most circumstances.

> Wieviele seid ihr?

- Ich bin alleine (hier)
- (Nur) Einer
- Nur ich

> Wieviele Personen?
>
> Für wieviele?

- Ich bin alleine (hier)
- (Für) Eine Person
- Für Einen
- Einen

Comment: Another possibility would be "nur ich" (="just me")